# Qual o significado das siglas SISD, SIMD, MISD, MIMD? Qual a sua relação com programação?

Tags: terminologia, paralelismo, arquitetura-computadores

Em algumas respostas e perguntas eu vejo citações a esses acrônimos. Eles normalmente são encaixados na seguinte tabela:

```
                     | Single data | Multiple data
Single instruction   |  SISD       | SIMD
Multiple instruction |  MISD       | MIMD
```

Gostaria de saber:

- o que significam essas "instruções únicas/múltiplas"?
- e esses "dados únicos/múltiplos"?
- como esses conceitos afetam na hora de programar?

### Exemplos de uso

- Nesta resposta sobre CUDA/OpenCL: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/86356/64969; ele usa SIMD para falar de coprocessadores como GPGPU e MIMD para paralelismo geral em núcleo de CPU
- Nesta pergunta: [Na arquitetura MISD, os threads executados são independentes e manipulam dados diferentes?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/207354/64969); sobre uma prova de concurso público brasileiro

Answer (score 4):

Essa tabela é conhecida como esquema de Flynn e tenta categorizar os computadores paralelos --- existem outros esquemas como esse, mas em geral acabam sendo imprecisos (este também).

Ela é baseada em dois conceitos: o fluxo de instruções e fluxo de dados. O fluxo de instruções conta quantas instruções são executadas, já o fluxo de dados consiste no conjunto de operandos dessas funções.

Em linhas gerais esses fluxos são independentes e portanto podemos combiná-los da maneira que quisermos, o que resulta nos 4 tipos do esquema.

**1. SISD** - *Single instruction - Single Data*

SISD é a representação no esquema de Flynn do clássico computador de von Neumann. Ele possui apenas um fluxo de instrução e de dados, de modo que apenas uma operação é feita por vez --- puramente sequencial.

**2. SIMD** - *Single instruction - Multiple Data*

Máquinas desse tipo possuem apenas um fluxo de instrução, mas possuem múltiplas unidades de cálculo. Isso significa que a máquina é capaz de executar uma mesma instrução em um conjunto de dados de maneira simultânea.

Existe um exemplo clássico para esse tipo: os processadores vetoriais, mas estes estão cada vez mais raros. Todavia o conceito está mais vivo do que nunca, presente nos processadores *convencionais* através do uso das instruções SSE dos processadores modernos (do pentium III pra frente), além das placas de vídeo que são especializadas neste tipo de operação --- uma operação feita em uma imagem é uma mesma operação feita em vários dados (pontos diferentes da imagem).

**3. MISD** - *Multiple instruction - Single data*

Máquinas MISD operam várias instruções diferentes em um único dado. É quase que um modelo completamente teórico, sem nenhum exemplo real (embora algumas pessoas usem o pipeline de instruções como exemplo de máquina MISD).

**4. MIMD** - *Multiple instruction - Multiple data*

São as máquinas que possuem CPUs independentes, onde cada unidade processante atua com instruções diferentes em dados diferentes. Os processadores com mais de um núcleo caem nesse modelo.

---

> - o que significam essas "instruções únicas/múltiplas"?

É o número de instruções diferentes que são executadas ao mesmo tempo.

Considere a máquina de von Neumann, nela a próxima instrução que será executada é apontada pelo registrador PC (*program counter*), logo a instrução executada é uma única. Se você possuí mais de um registrador PC, caso dos processadores do tipo  *multi-core* onde cada núcleo possuí o seu próprio PC, as instruções executadas são múltiplas e cada uma é apontada por um PC diferente.

> - e esses "dados únicos/múltiplos"?

Análogo, é a quantidade de operandos que são utilizados pela função.

Novamente considerando a máquina de von Neumann, se você quiser multiplicar um vetor inteiro por uma constante você precisa multiplicar elemento a elemento por esta constante. Em uma máquina SIMD essa multiplicação ocorre de maneira simultânea, onde a instrução executada é a mesma em todas as unidades processantes.

> - como esses conceitos afetam na hora de programar?

É uma pergunta complicada. Teoricamente você não precisa saber de nenhum desses conceitos, já que tudo pode ser feito utilizando uma máquina SISD.

Maas, somos sedentos por desempenho e buscamos resolver os problemas da maneira mais rápida possível. Conhecer esses conceitos permite que você tenha um leque maior de ferramentas na hora de desenvolver uma aplicação e, por consequência, desenvolva um programa mais eficiente.

Comment: Tragam um mito pra esse oscar! Me ajudou bastante nos meus estudos, obrigado pela contribuição Felipe!